# nvidia-smi looks good, but get code=30(cudaErrorUnknown) "cudaGetDeviceCount(&device_count)"

Tags: cuda, nvidia

The nvidia-smi command correctly executes, showing the expected GPU devices for my server. However, when I attempt to run the clock CUDA sample, I get the following error:

CUDA Clock sample
CUDA error at ../../common/inc/helper_cuda.h:1133 code=30(cudaErrorUnknown) "cudaGetDeviceCount(&device_count)"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ah! Figured it out. I had to upgrade the version of CentOS we are using. The unknown error indicated that a dependent library mismatch was the problem.

To fix, I upgraded the OS and then reinstalled the drivers